# Should I get all images with MySQL or show it with help of cURL?

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I can get all images from one website by ids via curl and save ids in my database and photos in ftp.

Or I can show those images getting them directly with cURL help every page load.

Which is more optimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning to curl multiple times per pageload, I would highly recommend that you instead scrape them down on beforehand and store them locally. This would mean that you don't need to open (timeconsuming) connections to other hosts, and it benefits both you and the end-user.

Short answer: The most optimal approach would be to store them on beforehand, ie not using multiple curls per pageload.

Comment: and if I use one curl, is it ok to not store it on beforehand?

Comment: One cURL-operation would still cripple the webpage during pageload, resulting in it taking everything from 1 second to 30 seconds to display the page. What happens if the "target website" is down - how will you provide the content to your users? I believe that the pros are overwhelmed by the cons upon cURL:ing on each pageload, but in the end it's up to you what you decide to do! :-)